# Как реализовать в C# закольцованный двунаправленный список?

Tags: c#, list

Существует ли в C# встроенный класс реализующий функцию закольцованного списка? Ну т.е. мне нужен обычный список, но последний элемент, которого ссылается на первый, как на следующий. Конечно весь функционал по добавлению, удалению, перемещению и т.д. должен брать на себя класс. Со стороны клиента что-то вроде:

```
var ring = new Ring<string>();
ring.Add("зима");
ring.Add("весна");
ring.Add("лето");    
ring.Add("осень");

foreach(var item in ring)
{
   var msg = string.Format("Наступила(о) {0}", item);
   MessageBox.Show(msg);
   Thread.Sleep(TimeSpan.FromMonthes(3));
}
```

Если готового класса нет, как правильно реализовать? Как я понимаю, реализую интерфейс `class Ring<T> : IList<T>` и добавляю, что еще нужно для задуманного функционала.

Comment: List в шарпе подразумевает конечную коллекцию, тогда как в вашем случае - коллекция будет бесконечной. Или я чего-то не понимаю в ваших терминах. Добавление элементов возможно? Ссылки на след.\пред. элементы проставляются автоматически или ручками?

Comment: @Monk, уточнил вопрос по вашему комментарию. Спасибо.

Comment: Ну можно `LinkedList` замкнуть, хотя я не уверен что ему это понравится, но это как раз двусвязный список, который вы хотели. Или сделать свой вариант на его основе, подсмотреть можно тут http://referencesource.microsoft.com/System/R/df5a6c7b6b60da4f.html

Comment: @rdorn, огромное спасибо за пример! после его изучения моя жизнь никогда уже не будет прежней ((:

Comment: это вы еще в исходники WinForms не заглядывали, там еще чудесатее =)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Надеюсь, я не сильно промахнулся. Наивная реализация за 5 минут на коленке выглядит у меня вот так:

```
  public class Ring<T> : ICollection<T>, IEnumerator<T>
  {
    private List<T> list = new List<T>();

    public IEnumerator<T> GetEnumerator()
    {
      return this;
    }

    IEnumerator IEnumerable.GetEnumerator()
    {
      return GetEnumerator();
    }

    public void Add(T item)
    {
      list.Add(item);
    }

    public void Clear()
    {
      list.Clear();
    }

    public bool Contains(T item)
    {
      return list.Contains(item);
    }

    public void CopyTo(T[] array, int arrayIndex)
    {
      list.CopyTo(array, arrayIndex);
    }

    public bool Remove(T item)
    {
      return list.Remove(item);
    }

    public int Count { get { return list.Count; } }
    public bool IsReadOnly { get { return false; } }
    public void Dispose()
    {

    }

    public bool MoveNext()
    {
      if (list.Count == 0)
       return false;

      index = list.Count > index + 1 ? index + 1 : 0;
      Current = list[index];
      return true;
    }

    public void Reset()
    {
      index = 0;
    }

    private int index = 0;

    public T Current { get; private set; }

    object IEnumerator.Current
    {
      get { return Current; }
    }
  }
```

С такой реализацией ваши времена года крутятся на ура.
Возможно, тут есть какие то проблемы, но в целом - примерно так можно реализовать циклический перебор по коллекции в одном `foreach`.
`For` на такой коллекции уже не будет гонять по циклу, потому что мы честно говорим, сколько внутри элементов.

Comment: "For на такой коллекции уже не будет гонять по циклу" - смотря какое условие на выход из `for`... или c# задаёт какие-то ограничения на это условие?

Comment: @4per ну да, но именно каноничная реализация по `ring.Count` обломается. Тут скорее `while(True)` надо гонять тогда уж =)

Comment: а как же классика `for(int i = 0; ; i=(i+1)%N){ }`? Это даже по обычному массиву будет бегать кругами заданной длины =)

Comment: @rdorn `for` под любые условия можно написать, тут я с вами согласен. Да и мой вариант кольца явно расчитан только на `foreach`.

Comment: Ну почему только foreach, можно же копию массива получить и по ней бегать как нравится. Другой вопрос что классический двунаправленный список подразумевает возможность перебора в обе стороны, Так что возможно стоит делать отдельные LR- и RL- энумераторы, но это скорее к автору вопрос, чем к вам.

Comment: @rdorn, да накрутить MovePrior() и всё такое, на основе примера не проблема. Главное, что мне показали - что стоит использовать стандартный элемент списка, как приватное поле класса (black-box reuse по GoF, на сколько усвоил), а для работы с foreach и другими ништяками реализовать стандартные же интерфейсы.

Comment: @Monk, единственное что меня смущает - реализация  GetEnumerator. Мне кажется, что могут быть проблемы, если вызвать его повторно до окончания использования первого... или это нормально?

Comment: @4per я честно сказал, что это на коленке накиданный код. Вполне возможно, что он будет вести себя не так, как ожидается. Я вообще не уверен, как ведут себя перечисления, если их вызывать внутри самих себя или просто повторно. Далеко не всё можно так использовать.